# split operator from string using loop concepts

Tags: c#

I have a query like I have an input like

```
AB_C + ABC_D/ * ABC_DE/ =ABC.AVO
```

In that I need to split only(*,+,=) operators, others will in a list form.
how can I achieve this in c#.net

I expect the output

`list 1={"AB_C","ABC_D/","ABC_DE/","ABC.AVO"}
 list 2={"+","*","="}`

Comment: Please provide more details: what have you tried so far? what did the code you wrote do? how was that different from what you wanted or expected? what _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing site. You are expected to make an effort to solve your problem yourself, to share the results of that effort, and to keep your question focused on some specific, narrow aspect of the problem you're trying to solve. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for additional information on how to write a good, answerable question for this web site.

Comment: I am really sorry for inconvenience, actually I am new for using this website, I will change all my mistakes, thank u so much for your valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s ="AB_C + ABC_D/ * ABC_DE/ =ABC.AVO";

    string[] chars = {};
    string[] op = {};
    string l="";
    int idx=0;
    int it=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]='+' || s[i] == '=' || s[i] =='/' || s[i] =='*')
        {
            if(l.length>=1)
            {
                chars[++idx] = l;
                l = ""; 
            }
            op[it] = s[i];
        }
        else
        {
            l = l + s[i]; 
        }
    }
    if(l.length>=1)
    {
        chars[++idx] = l;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first list can be achieved with String.Split().  The second list can be achieved by iterating over the input and looking at each character:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "AB_C + ABC_D/ * ABC_DE/ =ABC.AVO";

        string operators = "*+=";
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>(input.Split(operators.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        for(int i =0; i<list1.Count; i++)
        {
            list1[i] = list1[i].Trim();
        }
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if(operators.Contains(input.Substring(i,1)))
            {
                list2.Add(input.Substring(i, 1));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("list1 = " + String.Join(",", list1.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine("list2 = " + String.Join(",", list2.ToArray()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Note that this doesn't tell you if the input is valid.  There could be two operators next to each other, for instance, or no value after an operator, etc...